# Display Files (.lnk) with their real extension and real path

Tags: cmd.exe, regedit

I'm trying to display the content of (Recent files ) in windows .The problem that

> dir Recent

will generate all files with (.lnk extension ) .What i want is to display name of files with real extension  .it is possible to do that using Command prompt (cmd) .Can someone suggest solutions . I'm not interested in program that do that ,I just want to do that with cmd . I tried to display full extension (exemple .pdf.lnk ) then redirect result to file and delete ".lnk" but

> reg add HKCUSoftwareMicrosoftWindowsCurrentVersionExplorerAdvanced /v
>   HideFileExt /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

But it doesn't work for me [link](https://securityblog.gr/1657/hideshow-extensions-for-known-file-types-from-cmd/) . I'm using windows 8.1

Comment: Go to that folder with `cmd` command and type `attrib` command.

Comment: It displays files with .lnk extension and current path : Exemple A            C:\Users\*******\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\index.lnk
            C:\Users\*******\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\summary.lnk

Comment: Doesn't that solve your problem?

Comment: No , I want command that displays (File1.pdf.lnk ) not File1.lnk . Using only Cmd .

Comment: That depends on how you rename that shortcut. If you remove PDF letter from the shortcut name, it will not show in CMD.

Comment: Can i change parameter of folder and make extension visible .and the when i run automatically (dir command) it will display file1.pdf.lnk .https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000573.htm#show i want to do same thing but using cmd .